# SImple click a button event every second

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to be able to perform a 'click' event every second. I can create a function that runs every second, but not actually perform a 'click' event. Is there something daft I'm doing here? Feels like it should be an easy achievement.

I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"

Why is this error occurring, and how can it be fixed? I want to just program the click and not have to click the button manually, and another Stack Overflow post suggested just using .click().

Thanks for any help here...

```js
function click_fn() {
  console.log('button clicked...');
}


function yourFunction(){
    //console.log('testy');
    document.querySelector('tes').click();

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
}

yourFunction();
```

```html
<button class='tes' onclick='click_fn()'>test</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite descriptive, document.querySelector('tes') is returning null, and so .click can not be resolved on null, hence the error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"

Here is a working snippet (based on JamesT comment)

```js
function click_fn() {
  console.log('button clicked...');
}


function yourFunction(){
    // console.log('testy');
    document.querySelector('.tes').click();

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
}

yourFunction();
```

```html
<button class='tes' onclick='click_fn()'>test</button>
```

Comment: to further expand on this, the proper selector for the markup that was provided should look like this: `document.querySelector('.tes')`

Comment: I'm sure the poster would like to know __why__ the period (.) is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to select an element by a `class selector` you need to prefix it with a `.<classname>`

```js
function click_fn() {
  console.log('button clicked...');
}


function yourFunction(){
    //console.log('testy');
    document.querySelector('.tes').click(); // Add . prefix

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
}

yourFunction();
```

```html
<button class='tes' onclick='click_fn()'>test</button>
```